# grails mongodb connection refused

Tags: mongodb, grails, cloud-foundry

My grails app can connect to my local mongodb and works fine but when I deploy to cloud foundry, I get a connection refused error trying to connect to mongodb on cf.

I bound a mongodb service to my app, but it still can't connect?

barry-alexanders-MacBook-Pro:~ barryalexander$ vmc apps

```
+-------------+----+---------+-------------------------+-----------------+
| Application | #  | Health  | URLS                    | Services        |
+-------------+----+---------+-------------------------+-----------------+
| RelCal      | 1  | RUNNING | relcal.cloudfoundry.com | mongodb-a77900c |
| barry       | 1  | STOPPED | barry.cloudfoundry.com  |                 |
+-------------+----+---------+-------------------------+-----------------+
```

Here's the stack trace after hitting my app at http://relcal.cloudfoundry.com/release/calendar

```
        Line | Method
    ->> 228 | _open    in com.mongodb.DBPort
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |   112 | go       in     ''
    |    79 | call . . in     ''
    |   218 | call     in com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector
    |   305 | __find . in com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection
    |   369 | _check   in com.mongodb.DBCursor
    |   498 | _hasNext in     ''
    |   523 | hasNext  in     ''
    |    40 | hasNext  in com.google.code.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator
    |   258 | asList   in com.google.code.morphia.query.QueryImpl
    |    20 | doCall . in com.gap.release.calendar.RelCalRestController$_closure1
    ^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread
```

I'm missing something but don't know what.

Comment: If you open a private ticket at http://support.cloudfoundry.com and send us your app, we'll try and reproduce your problem.

Comment: opened private issue #102548 Mongodb service connection issue

Answer (score 1):

At this time, when deploying grails/mongo apps to cloudfoundry, it's best to use the approach described at [Cloud Foundry Services - Using MongoDB with Grails](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/services/mongodb/grails-mongodb.html)  rather than using morphia.